# is it possible to selecte multiple contacts from contact picker?

Tags: android, checkbox, contacts

i am using contact picker, is it possible to select multiple contacts with the help of checkbox in contactpicker activity? is there any other possible way?
P.S: now i am using a contactpicker activity,which helps to get a single contact! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` you can create a contact picker with multiple selections.

I guess you want to implement the functionality as shown below in this image:

[image]

Comment: is it not possible to use the ready available contactpicker Intent?

Comment: No you can only select one contact at a time using the standard Contact Picker URI

Comment: Thank You! :-( there is no below image!

Comment: HI Vikas can please explain me or give me some hint for multiple selection of contect.

Comment: Vikas Patidar Show the Code that you have used

Comment: @VikasPatidar where's the code for this. pls post the code here.

Comment: @TapanDesai have u tried any of sample? if so post it in another thread. we will be able to guide

Comment: @Ads i have tried many sample and you can see my thread here.. but why dont you share the code which helped you in achieving this???

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338160/get-details-of-contact-selected-from-list-view

Comment: @TapanDesai Really sorry i dont have the code now,let me know if u need any help in your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338160/get-details-of-contact-selected-from-list-view