# Contact Picker tutorials

Tags: android, contacts, picker

Hey does anyone know of any good contact picker tutorials for android? I need to make a contact picker that will allow for multiple selections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer work for you? [is it possible to selecte multiple contacts from contact picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192559/is-it-possible-to-selecte-multiple-contacts-from-contact-picker/4192629#4192629)

For tutorials:

- http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/49-other-coding-problemsarticles/1242-tutorial-reading-contacts-in-android-2
- http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/