# get details of contact selected from list view

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts

i am designing application in which i want to allow user to select multiple contact to send messages to. I have successfully retrieved the list of user in the listview with checkbox using the following code. now i want that when the user clicks on the "DONE" button, the **PHONE NUMBER of the all selected contact should be retrieved in EDITTEXT** in format like **John <+919898xxxxxx>, Rick <+919988xxxxxx>** and also that all the phone numbers containing **just 10 digits i.e "9898xxxxxx" should be stored in a string seperated by comma (9898xxxxxx, 9988xxxxxx)** automatically. how can i accomplish the requirement.

```
public class ContactsActivity extends ListActivity {

protected static final String TAG = null;
public String[] Contacts = {};
public int[] to = {};
public ListView myListView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    final Button done_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_Button);
    final Button clear_Button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.clear_Button);
    Cursor mCursor = getContacts();
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mCursor,
            Contacts = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
            to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    myListView = getListView();
    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    clear_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Selections Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ClearSelections();
        }
    });

    /** When 'Done' Button Pushed: **/
    done_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v){
            Log.i(TAG,":Done Button Selected:");
            SparseBooleanArray selectedPositions = myListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            Log.i(TAG,"Number of Checked Positions: " + selectedPositions.size());
            for (int i=0; i<selectedPositions.size(); i++) {
                if (selectedPositions.get(selectedPositions.keyAt(i)) == true) {
                    //do stuff

                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void ClearSelections() {
    int count = this.myListView.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        this.myListView.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
}

private Cursor getContacts() {
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '"
            + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            sortOrder);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_contacts, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You should probably find out what kind of content you're getting from selectedPosition,get..... part of your code.

Comment: @JoxTraex i am not getting the real phone numbers of the selected contacts, instead i am getting some strange values..

Comment: Find out what those strange values are, it should be pertinent to your contact data.

Comment: @JoxTraex but how do i actually get the real phone numbers of all the selected contacts?

Comment: You should read how contacts are stored in android 2.2+ this will provide some insight (Hint: its not all in one table)

Comment: @JoxTraex can u pls provide a brief explanation about how should i get my goal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16861/discussion-between-tapan-desai-and-joxtraex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configured it finally

```
        done_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v){
            String name = null;
            String number = null;
            long [] ids = myListView.getCheckedItemIds();
            for(long id : ids) {
                Cursor contact = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id + "" }, null);
                while(contact.moveToNext()){
                    name = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    //name+=name;
                    number = contact.getString(contact.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    //number+=number;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " +name + "\n" + "Number: " + number , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String numberListString = "";

for (int i=0; i<selectedPositions.size(); i++) {
                if (selectedPositions.get(selectedPositions.keyAt(i)) == true) {
                    //do stuff
                    numberListString  = numberListString + "," + numberAtCurrentSelectedPostion;

                }
            }

mEditText.setText(numberListString);
```

Comment: That is not particular useful. Care to explain how you obtain `numberListString`?

Comment: @Luksprog : Sorry about being unclear. `numberListString` would just be empty initially and we would keep on appending the current number to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your done button press:-

```
done_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name.clear();
            number.clear();
            Log.i(TAG, ":Done Button Selected:");
            SparseBooleanArray selectedPositions = myListView
                    .getCheckedItemPositions();
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Number of Checked Positions: "
                            + selectedPositions.size());
            Cursor cur = getContacts();
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedPositions.size(); i++) {
                if (selectedPositions.get(selectedPositions.keyAt(i)) == true) {
                    // do stuff
                    cur.moveToPosition(selectedPositions.keyAt(i));
                    name.add(cur.getString(1));
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                Cursor lCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, "DISPLAY_NAME = ? ",
                        new String[] { name.get(i) }, null);
                lCursor.moveToFirst();
                number.add(lCursor.getString(lCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                lCursor.close();
            }

        }
    });
```

where name and number are array list of type String. You will get all selected name and there numbers. Now you can show them in Edit Text as you like.

I think this will help you.